# Passing Matrices by Reference in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I've been working on passing R matrices to C++ functions using Rcpp and noticed some interesting behavior: An object of type NumericMatrix gets passed in by reference, while an object of type IntegerMatrix gets passed in by value.

For example, the following function changes the entry of the first row and column of a matrix to be 5:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void modify_matrix(NumericMatrix x
{
  x(0,0) = 5;
}
```

However, when I change the function to

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void modify_matrix(IntegerMatrix x)
{
  x(0,0) = 5;
}
```

or

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void modify_matrix(IntegerMatrix& x)
{
  x(0,0) = 5;
}
```

the function does nothing. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it works *if and only if you pass a matrix integers*:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/so51028610.cpp")

R> M <- matrix(1L, 2, 2)   # integer type

R> M                       # all ones
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

R> modify_matrix(M)        # call to mod

R> M                       # and changed
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    1
[2,]    1    1
R>
```

where you (minimally-modified) code plus the R call are

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void modify_matrix(Rcpp::IntegerMatrix x) {
  x(0,0) = 5;
}

/*** R 
M <- matrix(1L, 2, 2)   # integer type
M                       # all ones
modify_matrix(M)        # call to mod
M                       # and changed
*/
```

C and C++ are statically-typed languages. You have to worry about that more than you do in R.